# Unable to set the lookup with values on Entity form with lookup data from caller form in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

**Form: Entity  A**

- Field Display Name : Approver
- Field Name : bch_signingauthority
- Field Type : Lookup Field
- Source : User Entity
- Summarize : When Approver lookup in Entity: A is selected it will display a list of records from Entity: Users. Entity
- Name : bch_signingauthority

**Form: Entity B**

- Field Display Name: Approver
- Field Name: bch_approver
- Field Type: Lookup
- Field Source: From Entity: A and Field Name: Approver
- Summarize: When Approver lookup is selected it will display all saved records of Approver from Entity: A

**Functions:**
When I select an Approver in Entity: A and select an HTML button
I have used the code below to send a query string to the form Entity: B

```
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

function setDelegate(){

var ApproverInfo = new Array();
ApproverInfo = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute('bch_approver').getValue();
    if(ApproverInfo[0] != null)
    {
       
       var parameters = {};
       parameters["formid"] = "{b053a39a-041a-4356-acef-ddf00182762b}";
       window.parent.Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("bch_delegate", ApproverInfoId ); 
    }
}

</SCRIPT>

<META charset=utf-8></HEAD>
<BODY><INPUT onclick=setDelegate(); value="Set Delegate" type=submit> </BODY></HTML>
```

In Form Entity:B on Page Load I have written the following javascript code to read and set the lookup in Entity: B

I have received the query string using code below:

```js
// Get the Value of the Regarding through the Customer Parameters
var param = Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters();

if (param != null) {
  alert("inside");

  var ApproverId = param["bch_signingauthority"];
  var bchName = param["bch_name"];

  //Populate the Regarding if there is one
  //if (regardingId != undefined)
  //{Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").setValue([{id:regardingId, name:regardingName, entityType:regardingType}]);}
  var a = GetApproverName(ApproverId);
  var lookup = new Array();
  lookup[0] = new Object();
  lookup[0].id = bchName;
  lookup[0].name = a;
  //alert(a.trim());
  //alert(ApproverId);
  //lookup[0].entityType = 'Signing Authority';
  //Xrm.Page.getAttribute('bch_signingauthority').setValue(lookup);

  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("bch_signingauthority").setValue([
    { id: bchName, name: a, entityType: "Signing Authority" },
  ]);

  lookup[0] = new Object();
  lookup[0].id = ApproverId;
  lookup[0].name = a;
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("bch_approver_test1").setValue(lookup);
}

function GetApproverName(ApproverId) {
  var result = "";
  var serverUrl = document.location.href.substring(
    0,
    document.location.href.indexOf("/", 10)
  );
  var organizationName = Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName();
  serverUrl = serverUrl + "/" + organizationName;

  var fetchUtil = new FetchUtil(organizationName, serverUrl);

  var _fetchXMLGetUserName =
    "" +
    "   <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'> " +
    "     <entity name='systemuser'> " +
    "       <attribute name='fullname'/> " +
    "       <attribute name='systemuserid'/> " +
    //+ "       <attribute name='createdon' /> "
    //+ "       <attribute name='bch_approver' /> "
    "       <order attribute='fullname' descending='false' /> " +
    "       <filter type='and'> " +
    "       <condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='eq'  uitype='systemuser' value='" +
    ApproverId +
    " ' />" +
    "     </filter> " +
    "   </entity> " +
    "   </fetch> ";
  alert(_fetchXMLGetUserName);
  try {
    // Find System User
    var systemUser = fetchUtil.Fetch(_fetchXMLGetUserName);

    if (systemUser && systemUser.length > 0) {
      //  var signingAuthority = systemUser[0].attributes["bch_signingauthorityid"];
      //   alert(signingAuthority.value);

      // var name = systemUser[0].attributes["bch_name"];
      // alert(name.value);

      var systemUserName = systemUser[0].attributes["fullname"];
      //  alert(systemUserName.value);

      if (systemUserName != null && systemUserName.value != null) {
        result = systemUserName.value;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("An Error occured in GetUserName");
  }

  return result;
}
```

I am not able to set the Approver lookup/Name: bch_signingauthority with
ID being passed in via query string. Can you please help and suggest to me how to go about doing this as I am fairly new to CRM Dynamics 2011.

Comment: Related [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295899/5507/).

Answer (score 63):

You have a few issues with your `.setValue()` calls for Lookup attributes.

I recommend using [this helper function form the CRM SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_SetLookupFieldValue):

```
 function setSimpleLookupValue(LookupId, Type, Id, Name) {
    var lookupReference = [];
    lookupReference[0] = {};
    lookupReference[0].id = Id;
    lookupReference[0].entityType = Type;
    lookupReference[0].name = Name;
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute(LookupId).setValue(lookupReference);
 }
```

With that function you convert:

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute("bch_signingauthority").setValue([{ id: bchName, name: a, entityType: 'Signing Authority'}]);`

to

`setSimpleLookupValue('bch_signingauthority', 'Signing Authority', bchName, a);`

The next issue is that your code is using `"Signing Authority"` as the `entityType`. That is not a valid `entityType`, it should be the logical name of the entity that the Lookup references. In this, I believe that `bch_signingauthority` is a Lookup to `SystemUser` so it should be `'systemuser'`, and therefore read as follows:

`setSimpleLookupValue('bch_signingauthority', 'systemuser', bchName, a);`